# Should I use attack effect collision to detect when damage is dealt?

Tags: game-design, design-patterns

I am wondering what a common way for actually dealing damage to different units is. Imagine a game like starcraft for example, should damage be done like this:

> 1) zealot attacks zergling, deal damage to zergling

or

> 2) zealot attacks zergling, create an attack effect on zergling. When
>   this effect collides with the zergling deal damage to said zergling.

The advantage of 2 is for projectiles (like a dragoon attack) will deal damage when the attack collides with the target unit.

What are your thoughts about this in general? Are there other ways of doing this?

Comment: This is way too game-dependent to give an answer to.

Comment: There are usually a million ways to do anything. ;) To help narrow the field to the methods that will work well in *your* game, it's useful to include more details about the game you're building and what kinds of damage scenarios you need to handle. Do you have any particular cases that either style 1 or style 2 does not handle well? If so, please edit your question to tell us about those, and we can suggest ways to solve those specific issues.

Comment: Not saying this is a duplicate, as this seems to be more related to RTS than FPS, but understanding hitscan versus physics simulated bullets might help frame the question better: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13650/how-are-bullets-simulated-in-video-games

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are bullets simulated in video games?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13650/how-are-bullets-simulated-in-video-games)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to use particles or any FX related element to check collisions, as these can be very unreliable. I would recommend to either check the collision using hotboxes on the characters themselves, or define a basic mesh in the general shape of the attack animation to check the collsion with the attack effect. Hopefully that helps :)